# Why is my WordPress installation unable to create a directory?

Tags: permissions, apache2, wordpress

I am a new user of Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and I want to test WordPress on my local PC installation. I've only installed LAMP and the latest version of WordPress for now. Further actions were

- creating a directory `www` in `/home`, i.e `/home/www`
- install wordpress in it.
- changed Apache to use `/home/www` instead of `/var/www`

Apache is running smoothly & wordpress seems to be so as well. However, if try to change my background of my wordpress blog it throws an error

> Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2012/12. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Plese help me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

The webserver (Apache) runs as user `www-data` and group `www-data` by default. Change the filesystem permission on the directory the web application wants to write to - the "parent directory" as mentioned in the error message.

For example, do (prepend with `sudo` if you're not the current owner and need to elevate your own permissions in order to do it):

```
chown www-data /path/to/directory
```

to make `www-data` the owner which makes it writeable usually, or another approach via groups:

```
chgrp www-data /path/to/directory
chmod g+w /path/to/directory
```

If you don't understand this, start reading about how file system permission work in Linux.

Comment: Thank you gertvdijk... I am new comer to Ubuntu Family, So i have a little knowledge how file system permission work in Linux.

Comment: @Ankur No problem - I suggest to practice it using [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/67987/htg-explains-how-do-linux-file-permissions-work/) (just one out of many).